# How to remove lettering on gradient (Photoshop)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gradient, fill

I have an existing image with letters over a gradient. How would you go about removing it and replacing it with new lettering? Is there an easier way than to fill the whole are with a similar gradient? Content Aware Fill did not work.

Comment: I'm afraid a sample image may be necessary. If it's a straight gradient, you can just redraw the gradient on a new layer.

Answer (score 1):

Well, that depends on whether the layers of the image are merged or not. If the image is flattened, it would be hard to get a nice finish with absolutely no traces of manipulation. You have mentioned that it is an existing image, is it a .jpeg file?

If you know the exact color values of the gradient, you can create a new gradient over the text layer.

If you don't, try sampling the colors and get the closest match. The gradient won't be precisely the same, but it will be very similar.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Rita, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!